# Fetch new entities only

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

I thought Datastore's `key` was ordered by insertion date, but apparently I was wrong. I need to periodically look for new entities in the Datastore, fetch them and process them.

Until now, I would simply store the last fetched `key` and wrongly query for anything greater than it.

Is there a way of doing so?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datastore automatically generated keys are generated with uniform distribution, in order to make search more performant. You will not be able to understand which entity where added last using keys.

Instead, you can try couple of different approaches.

1. Use Pub/Sub and architecture your app so another background task will consume this last added entities. On entities add in DB, you will just publish new Event into Pub/Sub with key id. You event listener (separate routine) will receive it.
2. Use names and generate you custom names. But, as you want to create sequentially growing names, this will case performance hit on even not big ranges of data. You can find more about this in Best Practices of Google Datastore.
   https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/best-practices#keys
3. You can add additional creation time column, and still use automatic keys generation.

Comment: Thank you! I will have to rethink my solution!